# How to use a for loop or an array to shorten a if else script with similar IDs

Tags: jquery

I have this script which show and hides an input field based on value of a drop down. I have multiple dropdowns and multiple input fields to show, so I did ifelse. But how can I use a for loop or an array to make this script shorter. My IDs are similar with a number at the end of it.

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Other"){

          if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop0'){
               $('#bedConfigOther0').show();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop1'){
              $('#extraSetBedConfigOther1').show();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop2'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther2').show();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop3'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther3').show();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop4'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther4').show();
          }
    }else if( $(this).val() != "Other"){
         if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop0'){
               $('#bedConfigOther').hide();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop1'){
              $('#extraSetBedConfigOther1').hide();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop2'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther2').hide();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop3'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther3').hide();
          }
          else if( this.id == 'bedconfigdrop4'){
               $('#extraSetBedConfigOther4').hide();
          }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here man:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Other"){
        for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
           if(this.id == 'bedconfigdrop'+i) {
                $('#bedConfigOther'+i).show()  
                break;
           }
        }

    }else if( $(this).val() != "Other"){
        for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
           if(this.id == 'bedconfigdrop'+i) {
                $('#bedConfigOther'+i).hide()  
                break;
           }
        }
    }
});
```